# How to pass both formData and Json in POST request

Tags: javascript, html, http, post

I am trying to pass both formData and an apiKey in the body of a POST request, but it seems like its not working in my code below. What is the right syntax of doing that?

```
static login = (formData) => {
    return fetch('/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: { formData,
              JSON.stringify({
                 apiKey: 'xxxxxxxx'
              }) },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    }).then(r => r.json())
  }
```

Comment: This doesn’t look like python…

Comment: This is not valid python syntax. You need to be more clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sry its in js. Im trying to send both a json and a formData POST to back-end

Comment: Are you getting an error? What isn't working?

Comment: the syntax is wrong, but im not sure how to send 2 contents in body...

Comment: Hey there why does it say static, if that's js? Also why are you trying to use an object with all values and no keys?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that's just `request-promise`, but here

```
var login = (formData) => {
    return fetch('/api/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: { formData:formData,
            json:JSON.stringify({
                apiKey: 'xxxxxxxx'
            })
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    }).then(r => r.json())
}
```

The body object needs to have keys assigned to the values
On the server, you can access them as `body.formData` and `body.json`

Comment: I solved the problem by adding an apiKey field in the form, and assign apiKey value by: formData.set('apiKey', 'xxxxx') which works. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I be happy to help